# Backbone Marionette - Add a visual effect when switching view

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Is there a convenient way to add an effect when I leave a page (close a view/layout) and open a new one in the same region ? (something like a fade effect)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Marionette regions have a method called `open` that by default just replace the HTML of the old view with the new view. You can override this method to do any animation you like. From the [region documentation](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md):

### Set How View's `el` Is Attached

If you need to change how the view is attached to the DOM when
showing a view via a region, override the `open` method of the
region. This method receives one parameter - the view to show.

The default implementation of `open` is:

```
Marionette.Region.prototype.open = function(view){
  this.$el.html(view.el);
}
```

This will replace the contents of the region with the view's
`el` / content. You can change to this be anything you wish,
though, facilitating transition effects and more.

```
Marionette.Region.prototype.open = function(view){
  this.$el.hide();
  this.$el.html(view.el);
  this.$el.slideDown("fast");
}
```

This example will cause a view to slide down from the top
of the region, instead of just appearing in place.

Comment: FYI, the `open` method is now `attachHtml`in recent versions of Marionette. Checkout: http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.region.html#set-how-views-el-is-attached

Answer (score 7):

You could override the `close` function on the view, doing something like this:

```
close: function () {
  // fancy fade-out effects
  Backbone.Marionette.View.prototype.close.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

And do something similar with your `render` functions.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to work for me:

```
this.views = {
    messageItem: Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: Handlebars.templates.messaging_item,
        tagName: "li",
        className: "messaging-item",
        render: function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
            this.$el.hide();
        },
        onShow: function(){
            this.$el.slideDown(800);
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: Where would you put this page? In your app.js?

Comment: This led me to my answer.

Comment: I put the following into my onShow method for the view that is used for each item in a collection. Solved the problem perfectly. Putting the hide in the render was breaking things for me.
    `this.$el.hide();`
    `this.$el.slideDown("fast");`

Answer (score 3):

For future users people could user my plugin for Transition Support in marionette.

https://github.com/saqibshakil/Marionette.TransitionRegion/

I used css3 transitions as those have more hardware support than jquery animations. on the downside using this makes the code async so be carefull of that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be useful for you.

The following marionette plugin that adds 4 kind of transitions. There can be easily added more transition types.

Basically instead of using yourRegion.show(view)...
you can use now yourRegion.showAnimated(view, {animationType: 'yourAnimation'});

it's very easy to use.

https://github.com/marcinkrysiak1979/marionette.showAnimated

see the documentation on github for more info