# How do I go about overriding Backbone Marionette's Region with coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js, marionette

I have a congif file that I would like to use to override Backbone Marionette's default open method via a region.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is animate the way new regions are displayed. After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673445/backbone-marionette-add-a-visual-effect-when-switching-view), I know that it's possible to override, I'm just not to sure how to do it in a separate coffee script file.

I started off by simply trying to override the show method, but I can't even seem to get that to work:

```
do (Marionette) ->
    _.extend Marionette.Region,
    console.log "Extend Marionette called" ## This console.log is called so I know it's loading

        show: (view) ->
            console.log "Marionette extend Region Called" ## This console.log is not called when new regions are being displayed
```

So what I'm trying to do is extend the open method as show in this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673445/backbone-marionette-add-a-visual-effect-when-switching-view) I'm just trying to put it in it's own separate config fig file.
How do I override the open method for marionette's region in a separate config file?

Answer (score 1):

After reaching out to the #Marionette IRC Channel, I was able to get some help and solve this problem:

```
do (Marionette) ->
    _.extend Marionette.Region::,

        open: (view) ->
            @$el.hide()
            @$el.html(view.el)
            @$el.slideDown(600)
```

Simple as that.