# Backbone Marionette animate a CollectionView

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

If I have a CollectionView that is rendered and I reset the Collection with new data, how could I fade out the current collection view and then fade it back in with the new collection data?

Comment: Which version of Marionette do you use?

Comment: check out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673445/backbone-marionette-add-a-visual-effect-when-switching-view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673445/backbone-marionette-add-a-visual-effect-when-switching-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this, in my onion, is to call the `collection.reset` function ont he complete of an `jQuery.animation`. Say your collection lives in an element with class `collection`, then I would do this,

```
var that = this;
$('.collection').animate({ opacity: 0 }, { complete: function() {
    that.collection.reset(newModels);
    // Now to fade it back in
    $(this).animate({ opacity: 0 });
  }
});
```

You can run those lines from inside your view when you're ready to reset the collection. If you have a lot rendering that has to happen then you're might want to shoot off a pre-loader (a spinner, for example) inside the `complete` function right before the `collection.reset` (i.e., as soon as the images are hidden)